# Can I use ONLY Function Keys ("F11" for example) as a hot key in Java FX?

Tags: menu, javafx-8, hotkeys, scenebuilder

I am trying to create some menu options for a desktop application using JavaFX.  One requirement that has been requested is to map the Function Keys <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> to specific actions, without requiring a modifier key like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, etc.

Is this possible?  When I am trying to add these in SceneBuilder, the UI seems to require the modifier - it won't allow me to select "none" + <kbd>F11</kbd> for example.

Thanks.

Comment: hmm ... it's a problem of scenebuilder only, right? Because plain coding like `.put(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F10), () -> LOG.info("got accelerator "))` just seems to work. As @ulukbiy already answered, guilty of not reading .. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was dynamically creating the menu - I am able to do the following:

```
mi.setOnAction(event -> {
                ...do some stuff
            });
            if(child.hasKeyCode())){
                KeyCode kc = KeyCode.getKeyCode(child.getKeyCode());
                mi.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(kc));              }
            parentMenu.getItems().add(mi);
```

[Edit]

I found that in SceneBuilder, if you select one modifier and change the value in the FXML from ANY or DOWN to UP then the function key, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this

```
scene.getAccelerators().put(
        new KeyCodeCombination( KeyCode.F10 ),
        new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // just do action
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Thanks - this pointed me to the solution.  You are correct that this is a SceneBuilder issue.